# Two dimensional integral gives a volume, but what if I don't deal with distances and volumes?

Tags: calculus, integration, unit-of-measure

I have I believe a simple question which relates to two-dimensional integral. I have been reading enough (and watch video tutorials) on the technique to hopefully understand it well. Every tutorial takes the assumption that we measure somehow the "volume" under a surface when we deal for instance with two-dimensional integrals:

$z = \int_x \int_y f(x,y)dx dy$

Let me know if I get that wrong, but I think it is a generally good answer. The problem I have in this. I am trying to understand two-dimensional integrals within a different context. More precisely I am reading a book on computer graphics, in which they say that pixels of an image represent radiance, and that this radiance needs to be computed with an integral over the pixel's area. Something like this:

$L_{pixel} = \int_{pixel area} L(x)dx$

where L stands for radiance. I understand this as well more or less, but then if a two dimensional integral applied to a surface gives a volume, what is the unit of a two-dimensional integral applied to radiance over the area of pixel? I would expect radiance as well, but since the integral of a surface give cubic meters, shouldn't it be something else than radiance? Cubic radiance? What is the meaning of the value returned?

I am sure I am just being confused but would really appreciate if someone could clarify this for me.

Thank you.

Comment: you can also interpret it to be the 'area' of the region where the integrand gives density -- in fact these are more or less identical

Comment: @oldrinb. Thanks for you answer, it gives me a hint but I don't understand this clearly yet. The integrand being f(x,y) in this case or L(x). So do you suggest f(x,y) can be interpreted at providing some "local" density, while the double-integral of this function gives some sort of "area". Area of what since we already know the domain of integration in this case the area of the pixel? What would mean the area of radiance? Sorry I know I am not clear but it would be nice if you could elaborate a bit. Thank you.

Comment: yes @user18490 that is what I'm saying, something like [area density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_density). if you're bent on using 'units' to understand these, consider $L(x)$ to be radiance *density* (like radiance per square metre)

Comment: Great thank you very much I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the units of $\iint f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ are the units of $f$ times the units of $x$ times the units of $y$. If $x,y$ have units of length, then in order of the integral to make sense as Quantity of X, the units of $f$ must be "X per square meter", or simply *density of $X$*.

Here's another version: $\iiint f(x,y,t)\,dx\,dy\,dt$ where $x,y$ are as above and $t$ is time. Here $f$ could be *flux*, i.e.,  flow rate per unit area. This is measured in, say, kilograms per square meter per second. Then the integral is measured in kilograms: it's the total amount that passed through the given area in given time interval.

Answer (score 0):

The units of luminance are candela/(square meter), so the units of the integral are just candelas.

Keep in mind that the units for various light-related quantities are a little subtle, and I wouldn't be surprised if they are sometimes misused. Take a look at the Wikipedia article for "candela" and see in particular the table "SI photometric light units".